# Need assistance interpreting a for statement in inherited code

Tags: java, file-io, for-loop

Consider `for(File file : files )` in the following code. I've never seen this syntax before. I understand from context and behavior that it'a a for loop based on the number of records...similar to `(for x=0;x<length.foo;++x)`. Beyond that though, I'm not sure. Is this shorthand for a for loop that I've not learned yet? Is this a loop specifically for objects? More importantly... how do I describe it when I want to google information about that particular syntax?

CLARIFICATION: a second question, I'm also curious how this method of recursive file listing stores the list of filenames in `file`. Is this an array? a collection? or...? I'd like to know how I need to read the resulting file.

```
public static void main(String... aArgs) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    File startingDirectory= new File("CGT");
    List<File> files = WorkingFileListing2.getFileListingNoSort(startingDirectory);
    for(File file : files )
    {
       System.out.println(file);  //print filenames
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like the equivalent of a 'foreach' in C#. Searching Google for 'Java foreach' got me this:
[Detail on Java For-Each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

Answer (score 4):

It is the so-called ["for each" loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

> I'm also curious how this method stores the list of filenames in `file`.

It doesn't. It iterates over the elements of `files`, assigning them in turn to `file` (one at a time!). If you run the code, each iteration of the loop will print one filename.

> how do I describe it when I want to google information about that particular syntax?

Google "java for-each".

Comment: As a mostly C# guy I guess I was never going to get there first on a Java question...

Answer (score 2):

This is called [foreach loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) which is used for only objects when you dont want to remove object from the array.